# How do I pass a comma (,) as a parameter in a call statement

Tags: batch-file

I want to be able to pass a comma (`,`) to a `call` statement and use it as a variable, but the below doesn't seem to work:

```
:example

@echo off
call :test ,

echo %output%

pause

:test
set "output=%1"
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
call :test ","

echo %output%

pause
goto :eof

:test
set "output=%~1"
goto :eof
```

`,` is a separator, so if you want to pass it as a literal, you need to `"enclose it in quotes"`.

To remove enclosing quotes from a parameter, use `~`.

Note the extra `goto :eof`. This skips over the `:test` code once the `pause` is released.

Comment: @abelenky Yours may have been quicker, but this answer does a better job explaining *why* you need the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
REM Pass the , with Quotes around it.
call :test ","
echo %output%
pause


:test
REM Using ~ to remove the quotes
set "output=%~1"
goto :eof
```

---

**Output**

```
,
Press any key to continue . . .
```